# Memory leak / extreme memory use with HTML5 canvas and images

Tags: javascript, canvas, three.js

I on a project making projection of maps onto a point cloud possible in Potree.

We are loading the maps from OpenStreetMap's tile API and are loading more tiles as the user zooms on point cloud in order to give the user a more detailed experience. We are projecting the data from the tiles to the point cloud using Three.js Texture which we are extracting from a canvas element where we place the tiles.

We have made all we code to get the tiles from OSM, cut them in the right size and place them in the canvas. And the solution is working quite well for smaller point clouds, but as the area grows and more tiles/images are needed and the canvas element gets bigger (we are scaling the canvas to follow the zoom level in order to give a better resolution) we get into trouble with an huge memory use (around 10 gb in the task manager, but then I investigate the memory use in the chrome dev tools the memory use is a lot lower). The big memory use will cause the browser to become unresponsive and eventually die.

My question is there for is there some kind of memory leak in this code or something you have to be very careful about when you use images and canvasses?

The code:

```
Potree.MapTextureManager = class MapTextureManager {
constructor(projection, bbMin, bbMax) {
    this.projection = projection;
    this.bbMin = bbMin;
    this.bbMax = bbMax;
    this._mapCanvas = document.getElementById("texture");
    let ratio = (bbMax[0] - bbMin[0]) / (bbMax[1] - bbMin[1]);
    let minHeight = 256;
    this._mapCanvas.width = minHeight * ratio;
    this._mapCanvas.height = minHeight;
    this._minWeb = proj4(swiss, WGS84, [this.bbMin[0], this.bbMin[1]]);
    this._maxWeb = proj4(swiss, WGS84, [this.bbMax[0], this.bbMax[1]]);
    this.updateTexture(this._minWeb, this._maxWeb);
    this._cachedTexture = null;
    this._drawnImages = [];
    this.geometryNodeIds = new Set();
    this._cachedTileImages = [];
    this._currentMaxZoom = this.getTiles(this._minWeb, this._maxWeb)[0].zoom;
}

updateTextureFor(visibleNodes, matrixWorld) {
    visibleNodes.forEach(visibleNode => {
        if (!this.geometryNodeIds.has(visibleNode.geometryNode.id)) {
            this.geometryNodeIds.add(visibleNode.geometryNode.id);
            var swiss = proj4.defs("test");
            var WGS84 = proj4.defs("WGS84");
            let nodeBox = Potree.utils.computeTransformedBoundingBox(visibleNode.geometryNode.boundingBox, matrixWorld);
            let minWeb = proj4(swiss, WGS84, [nodeBox.min.x, nodeBox.min.y]);
            let maxWeb = proj4(swiss, WGS84, [nodeBox.max.x, nodeBox.max.y]);
            this.updateTexture(minWeb, maxWeb);
        }
    });
}

updateTexture(minWeb, maxWeb) {
    let canvasEl = this._mapCanvas;
    let tiles = this.getTiles(minWeb, maxWeb);
    let tilePromises = this.tilePromisesFor(tiles);
    tilePromises.forEach(tilePromise => {
        tilePromise.then(tileImage => {
            if (tileImage.tile.zoom > this._currentMaxZoom) {
                this.resizeCanvasTo(tileImage.tile.zoom);
            }
            this._cachedTileImages.push(tileImage);
            this._cachedTileImages.sort((tileImage1, tileImage2) => {
                if (tileImage1.tile.zoom >= tileImage2.tile.zoom) {
                    return 1;
                } else {
                    return -1;
                }
            });
            let myArray = this._cachedTileImages.filter((el) => !this._drawnImages.includes(el));
            myArray.forEach(tileImage => {
                // if (this._drawnImages.indexOf(tileImage) === -1) {
                this.drawTileOnCanvas(canvasEl, tileImage.image, tileImage.tile);
                this._drawnImages.push(tileImage);
                // }
            });
            if (this._cachedTexture) {
                this._cachedTexture.dispose();
                this._cachedTexture = null;
            }
        });
    });
}

get mapTexture() {
    if (this._cachedTexture) {
        return this._cachedTexture;
    }
    let texture = new THREE.CanvasTexture(this._mapCanvas);
    texture.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
    texture.needsUpdate = true;
    this._cachedTexture = texture;
    return texture;
}

getTiles(minCoord, maxCoord, zoom = 1) {
    let maxZoom = 18;
    let minNumberOfTiles = 4;
    let minX = this.long2tile(minCoord[0], zoom);
    let minY = this.lat2tile(minCoord[1], zoom);
    let maxX = this.long2tile(maxCoord[0], zoom);
    let maxY = this.lat2tile(maxCoord[1], zoom);
    let arrayX = [minX, maxX].sort();
    let arrayY = [minY, maxY].sort();
    let tiles = [];
    for (var x = arrayX[0]; x <= arrayX[1]; x++) {
        for (var y = arrayY[0]; y <= arrayY[1]; y++) {
            tiles.push({ X: x, Y: y, zoom: zoom });
        }
    }

    // We want at least minNumberOfTiles tiles per pointcloud node
    if (tiles.length >= minNumberOfTiles || zoom === maxZoom) {
        return tiles;
    } else {
        return this.getTiles(minCoord, maxCoord, zoom + 1);
    }
}

tilePromisesFor(Tiles) {
    return Tiles.map(function (tile, i) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let image = new Image(256, 256);
            image.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
            image.onload = function () {
                let data = { tile: tile, image: image };
                resolve(data);
            }
            image.src = "https://tile.openstreetmap.org" + "/" + tile.zoom + "/" + tile.X + "/" + tile.Y + ".png";
        })
    });

}


drawTileOnCanvas(canvas, image, tile) {
    let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(image, sX, sY, imageWidthToBeDrawn, imageHeightToBeDrawn, dX, dY, drawingWidth, drawingHeight);
    image.src = "";
    image = null;
}

resizeCanvasTo(zoom) {
    let canvas = this._mapCanvas;
    let multiplier = Math.pow(2, zoom - this._currentMaxZoom);

    let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    // create a temporary canvas obj to cache the pixel data //
    var temp_cnvs = document.createElement('canvas');
    var temp_cntx = temp_cnvs.getContext('2d');
    // set it to the new width & height and draw the current canvas data into it // 
    temp_cnvs.width = canvas.width * multiplier;;
    temp_cnvs.height = canvas.height * multiplier;;
    temp_cntx.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0);

    // resize & clear the original canvas and copy back in the cached pixel data //
    canvas.width = canvas.width * multiplier;
    canvas.height = canvas.height * multiplier;
    ctx.scale(multiplier, multiplier);
    ctx.drawImage(temp_cnvs, 0, 0);
    this._currentMaxZoom = zoom;
    temp_cnvs = null;
    temp_cntx = null;
        }
};
```

I have tried to remove some of the unnecessary code. So please say if you are missing something.

Comment: Most likely cause of problems is the canvas size, but the code given does not provide information required to know how big `this._mapCanvas` can get Growing pixel counts above what the GPU RAM can hold to render a single frame will have a significant performance hit. Count up all the pixels needed to render a single frame and multiply by 4. (the canvas and all the tiles drawn to that canvas) If that number is approaching GPU RAM size you will get Bus thrashing as images are moved between RAM to the GPU's RAM to render all the content

Comment: Hi. The canvas can get around 9200px*9200px before it crashes the whole application

Comment: 9200 squared * 4 is ~340Mb for just the canvas!!! Bet all runs smooth and then there is an abrupt performance drop (GPU Bus thrashing) . Most devices will have trouble with that image size, not  including all the tiles . Keep to the device display resolution (dynamic image content should never go over device display res as most info is lost in the down sample during render), or render only  the visible tiles directly (no need for the canvas) and save a ton of memory.